# Table-to-CSV supporting rowspan

Tags: jquery, csv, html-table

Like for JSON we have http://lightswitch05.github.io/table-to-json/
which support good feature like rowspan,columnspan
istheir something for CSV as well , i tried searching but coulnd't get any
Their is jquery tabletoCSV but it didnt support rowspan and columnspan.

Please suggest
UPDATE:
After some search I found this o be useful, it export html table to excel sheet as is 
jsfiddle.net/lesson8/wVejP/

Answer (score 0):

i think you want some thing like this http://jsfiddle.net/hybrid13i/JXrwM/

```
function JSONToCSVConvertor(JSONData, ReportTitle, ShowLabel) {}
```